# Laravel - guardar y recuperar imagen en el storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-4

tengo el siguiente código que lo uso para almacenar las imagenes que subo desde un formulario haciendo uso de dropzone

```
    /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
public function dropzonePromoStore(Request $request)
{

    $category_id = $request->query('id');

    $path_img = 'promos';

    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $file = $request->file('file');

    try {
        Storage::disk('public')->put($path_img . '/'. $category_id . '/'. $file->getClientOriginalName(), File::get($file));
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return response('error',400);
    }

    $imageName = $path_img . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

    return response()->json(['image' => $imageName]);
}
```

Al final lo que hace es guardar el fichero en una ruta del storage tal como esta

- "/promos/23/file1.png"
- "/promos/24/file2.png"

Y de esta forma guardo el link en la BD, ahora mi pregunta es como hago para mostrar dicho link y mostrarlo.

El virtualhost de mi proyecto esta configurado para que la ruta del proyecto laravel / public sea la raiz, y accedo al proyecto mediante

http://site1.local

Por lo que siguiendo con el ejemplo anterior si quiero mostrar el archivo subido lo haria de esta forma

http://site1.local/promos/23/file1.png <== pero este link no es válido

Por lo que mi pregunta (són 2 en 1) es como puedo probar uno de los archivos subidos y la segunda como debo recuperarlo para mostrarlo.

Gracias

Comment: Tienes creado link simbólico entre `/public` y `/storage/app/public`?

Comment: Trabajo en windows, en /public veo archivos como index.php y en storage/app/public veo carpetas distintas

Answer (score 1):

Como me comenta el compañero @porloscerros me faltaba crear el enlace simbólico con el comando

```
php artisan storage:link
```